# Where is ApiResources configuration in Identity Server 4 in ASP.NET 3.1?

Tags: identityserver4

Following the ASP.NET Core 2.2 tutorial to scaffold Identity Server 4 In-Memory project template, `ApiResources` configuration is at `appsettings.json`.

```
  "ApiResources": [
    {
      "Name": "movie.api",
      "DisplayName": "Movie API Services",
      "Scopes": [
        {
          "Name": "movie.api",
          "DisplayName": "Movie API Services"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

But, in ASP.NET Core 3.1, `appsettings.json` is not longer there but replaced with `Config.cs`. But, I could not locate `ApiResources` there. How do I create `ApiResources` in `Config.cs`.

This is my existing `Config.cs`

public static class Config
{
public static IEnumerable IdentityResources =>
new IdentityResource[]
{
new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
new IdentityResources.Profile(),
};

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new ApiScope[]
        {
            new ApiScope("scope1"),
            new ApiScope("scope2"),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        {
            // m2m client credentials flow client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "m2m.client",
                ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("511536EF-F270-4058-80CA-1C89C192F69A".Sha256()) },

                AllowedScopes = { "scope1" }
            },

            // interactive client using code flow + pkce
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "interactive",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0".Sha256()) },
                
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc" },
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44300/signout-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "scope2" }
            },

            // Client - Configure Identity Service
            // Step 2: Register client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "movie.web", // match with what defined in startup.cs
                //ClientSecrets = { new Secret("49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc" },
                //FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44300/signout-oidc",
                //PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signout-callback-oidc" },

                //AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile" },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser =  true
            },
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simplest way to make it work you can add it to `Config.cs` like this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            { 
                new ApiScope("movie.api")
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
            new ApiResource[]
            {
                new ApiResource("movie.api", "The Movie API")
                {
                    Scopes = { "movie.api" }
                }
            };
```

And add it to IdentityServer on `Startup.cs` like this:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
```

But in version 4 of IdentityServer4, scopes have their own definition and can optionally be referenced by resources. This means you dont have to have ApiResource if you dont need to.

Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html?highlight=ApiResource#api-resources)